# find solution for the variable y

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have some problem with understaing how [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bxy%2B2x%3D-1%22)
 calculate the solution for the variable $y$  in equation $2x^2+y^2+xy+2x=-1$

Comment: Quadratic Formula

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

the quadratic formula :

$$ ay^2 + by + c = 0 \Rightarrow y = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $$

let $$  a = 1 , b = x , c = 2x^2 + 2x + 1 $$